# show date and time insteed of only date in datepicker in php code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Normally in datepicker only date is display.
we can get user define date only and by default time is taken as 12:00:00
How can we get user define date and time both from datepicker.

Comment: look at this plugin that adds a timepicker to the datepicker - http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Answer (score 0):

You will need a 3rd party plugin, such as [Timepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)